# Does the IIS needs to be on the domain to use active directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, active-directory

I am building a intranet application for my company and it uses Form Authentication using active directory. When i run the application on my VS development studio is works fine. There are no issues. But when i deploy the application to a IIS Server which has anonymous access enabled using a local account, my application is reporting it cannot contact the Active Directory. My main aim is to validate the crendtials only. And I do not have administrator account on the AD.

Is this because, the server is not connected to a domain or is it because it has anonymous access turned on.

My workstation is connected to the domain and works fine when i run it on the VS development server.

If this because the server is not connected, than, is there any other ways to validate the user via the AD.

The silly part is that when i remote and try to use the browser to access Google or yahoo, windows will prompt me for username and password. I will enter my domain\username along with my password, and i will be able to access the internet. If this possible, than why I cant use the same way to authenticate my users to my application.

Here are details of my application

IIS and SQL on the same machine.
Server is not connected to the domain.
My personal workstation is connected to the domain.

Comment: Forms Authentication does not require AD, but it sounds like you need Windows Authentication ?

Comment: @sh1rts Yup, Forms Authentication does not need AD. But it can be implemented, Even when When i activate Windows Authentication, I have to enter the local server login credentials. It does not work with my AD credentials.

Comment: @sh1rts Forms Authentication with AD is recommended by some experts for multiple applications on a Intranet.  This gives them a more detailed access control on the application and for logging purpose.

Comment: If it's an intRAnet - no public access required - then there is no reason for the machine to be in a DMZ, and you can use Windows Authentication.